# How do I make something pop out from a button where I click it in Unity 2D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Do you know the on click animation from Cookie Clicker? When you click on the big cookie there is a small cookie poping out from where you clicked that jumps, falls and fades away. Can somebody help me make the little image appear and jump?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. create a particle system
2. edit it to be a burst of particles (10 of them at once)
3. write a input system that triggers an unity event when pressing a button
4. trigger the particle system via code

Particles tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FEA1wTMJAR0

how to Trigger them via script: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qOXD7oRXBKQ